# Filter vs Page Tabs?

Tags: tabs, content, sort, consistency, filter

Any UX issues, mainly on consistency, on mixing “filter based tabs” and “page based tabs” in a reporting system?

**Filter Tabs**:
In the below example, the content columns will remain the same however it will display either, all, uncategorized or categorized.

[image: Filter Tab]

**Page Tabs**:
In the below example, the content and design will change on each tab.

[image]

Comment: Not quite getting you.

Answer (score 1):

Users might get confused that the same UI pattern is used for two different reasons.

For the pages example, it's perfectly reasonable to break out that content over many tabs (as you did).

For the filter example, I would recommend using another method to display the active filters. Here are two examples:

[image]